# Using a MOSFET for FM transmitters output will it work?

Tags: mosfet, oscillator, frequency

What happens if a MOSFET (n type) is used for the output of a 100 MHz oscillator for the pins *G* and *S* from my knowledge MOSFET uses voltage in Gate to control the Drain and Source current unlike a transistor which uses current for Base and Emitter to control current in Collector and Emitter.

Since MOSFET's *G* and *S* acts as a capacitor in which allows AC to pass throw for example [IRF830](https://alltransistors.com/mosfet/transistor.php?transistor=2562) which has Total Gate Charge of 22 nC also Gate-Threshold Voltage of 4 V will it oscillate with the 100 MHz oscillation and oscillate the *D* and *S* current with a load (Hoping to put a tungsten blub there)?

My circuit diagram

[image]

R6 needs to be adjusted so that the *G* and *S* capacitor oscillates within the Gate Threshold range

Also when a very small tungsten blub (X-mas decoration type blub) is connected to the output of the 20 nf capacitor to ground it glows faintly. MOSFET and R6 R7 is not connected yet to the circuit. When I search the web everyone uses transistor to amplify the RF power but I don't have any high frequency power transistors and I don't like TO5 type transistors they are so hard to make a heat sink.

Comment: Your circuit won't work. Check the MOSFET connections. Why would you want to power a tungsten bulb with 100 MHz?

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake I will fix it now

Comment: To check if its working for not so that D and S is oscillating

Comment: Note that between C3 and Q3 gate, there is nothing to bias the gate voltage. Sure, AC can pass to it, but without some form of bias, it could float anywhere between cut-off and saturation.

Comment: Yeah that is why I did put R6 it needs to be adjusted so that it oscillates properly

Comment: First work out the current it takes to charge 22 nC 100 million times per second...

Comment: Yeah I guess you answered my question with 22nC having capacitance of 5.5 nF at 4 V it has a impedance of 0.289 ohms for 100 MHz frequency there is no way the MOSFET will work thanks